# How can I access my custom error message while using response.raise_for_status?

Tags: python, python-requests

I had an instance where the requests library was not catching the 404 and instead passing the code onto another error. To catch a 404, I've brought in the raise_for_status() method, which is correctly stopping the code at the HTTPError now. However, it no longer prints my custom error messaging and instead just gives me the stack trace.

Here's the code

```
        try:
            response = requests.request(
                request_type, url, headers=headers, data=payload
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.ConnectionError as ce:
            logger.info(
                f"""It appears you may need to check
                your internet connection - {ce}"""
            )
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as he:

            if response.raise_for_status() == 404:
                logger.info(
                    f"""We seem to be having an issue
                    with your request - {he.response}"""
                )
                logger.info(f"request - {he.request}")
        return response
```

and here is the full stack trace I'm getting when a 404 is received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/url_help/url_help.py", line 51, in connect_to_url
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api-url.com/item/v3/companies/8951507/persons?page=1&pageSize=10

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/main.py", line 99, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/main.py", line 50, in main
    ).get_employees_from_company_id(PAGE_SIZE, COMPANY_ID)
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/employee_dict/employee_dict.py", line 109, in get_employees_from_company_id
    response = Url.connect_to_url(
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/url_help/url_help.py", line 60, in connect_to_url
    if response.raise_for_status() == 404:
  File "/home/user/projects/project_code/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api-url.com/item/v3/companies/8951507/persons?page=1&pageSize=10
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get this to print/log the message? In all other instances, I can get the custom message to log in addition to the actual error coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise_for_status` is not a function that returns the code, but rather a function that will raise an exception if the status code is not ok. Use the `status_code` attribute instead. For example:

```
    try:
        response = requests.request(request_type, url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        if response.status_code == 404:
            logger.info(f"""We seem to be having an issue with your request - {he.response}""")
        else:
            response.raise_for_status()

    except requests.ConnectionError as ce:
        ...
```

If you'd like to still raise an exception in case of 404, just remove the `else:`, and unindent the following call to `response.raise_for_status()`.

Comment: thanks for the quick suggestion. Unfortunately, doing this just puts me in the same spot I was previously where the 404 gets hidden and I get an empty json response error. Since this is actually a 404, my code should stop there.

Comment: I edited the answer already, noting how "not" to hide the 404.. just remove the `else` and unindent the following line. Let me know if this helps

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the tip on that. I am getting both the error response along with my actual custom error messaging.

Answer (score 0):

`raise_for_status` is a method which raises Error when the http requests fails and returns nothing otherwise.

If you want to check the response status, you should check the `status_code`, i.e.,

```py
if response.status_code == 404:
    # do sth.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling raise_for_status again in the except block. This re-raises an exception, and it's not caught. Inside except block, you need to check status_code:

```py
        try:
            response = requests.request(
                request_type, url, headers=headers, data=payload
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.ConnectionError as ce:
            logger.info(
                f"""It appears you may need to check
                your internet connection - {ce}"""
            )
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as he:

            if response.status_code == 404:
                logger.info(
                    f"""We seem to be having an issue
                    with your request - {he.response}"""
                )
                logger.info(f"request - {he.request}")
        return response
```